# Will iOS guarantee complete delivery of a BLE characteristic value?

Tags: ios, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

When I ask iOS what the maximum value length is for BLE characteristics, it will typically give me a number that is more than 20 bytes. Usually it is around 150 or 200. This means that iOS can already break long characteristic values into packet-sized chunks and send them one by one. But does iOS guarantee complete delivery? I ask because I've heard that some BLE SoC devices will completely drop a connection in the middle of a characteristic transmission if any error occurs. What controls this behavior? Can iOS recover from a dropped connection or does it not try?

Comment: What does the specification say? What specifically is unclear or how does iOS deviate from the spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GATT transactions are cancelled if the connection is terminated before they finish.

iOS will not automatically reconnect to a slave device if a disconnection occurs; you will need to connect again and try to perform the GATT operation again.

Note that GATT writes are atomic, meaning that either the full value will be written, or nothing at all.

Comment: But why would a disconnect occur because of an error like a lost packet? Or is this just a misinterpretation of how BLE works?

Comment: BLE's link layer is constructed in a way that there can't be any packet losses. A packet is sent over and over until the remote device acknowledges the packet. After that, the next packet in the queue is sent. But if the remote device doesn't ack within the supervision timeout, the connection is considered lost. Also, higher up in the stack, at the ATT/GATT layer, if a response is not received within 30 seconds from the request, it's allowed to drop the connection. But in your case it rather seems to be some buggy device.